# create custom flex component in flex 4

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, custom-component

I need to create custom component like 
 // file name is say Comp.mxml

```
 < mx:VBox>
  < mx:Text id="txtId"/>
  < mx:Label id="lblId" />
< /mx:VBox >
```

// end mxml

in another actionscript file, I want to do like as follows:

```
for(count=0; count<10; count++) {
    var comp:Comp = new Comp();
    comp.txtId.text = "Text_"+count;
    comp.lblId.text = "Label_"+count;
    parentObjId.appendChild(comp);
    // parentObjId is a VBOX
}
```

Here, I need to create custom component object, changing their element values and appending that custom component in VBox. What are the correct syntax to implement this one? 
Please anybody provide solutions.

Comment: Your question is hard to follow, but I think you need a 'List' with your 'Comp' as an ItemRenderer.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to inherit from the VBox Class component

by creating severals classes as myVbox, myVbox2, myVbox2 ( better string names than numbers)

Answer (score 0):

An Item Renderer would be a far better solution.

Comment: can you pls explain or provide any sample link that i can follow

Comment: An item renderer is like a repeater.

Basically you bind it to a datagroup or a list, and then for how ever many pieces of data you have it will draw that many items.

So easy way.

Create a list, bind some date to it.

Then click in properties, and click itemrender (flex builder 4)
create a new one.

Then in the item renderer what ever field you want to get data from you simply bind using {data.clientid} assuming one of the fields in your list is called clientID.

Comment: Item renderers are one of the best features in flex period. They let you display data in anyway you want to draw it. 

Basically renderers are these cool mini apps that you can use to diplay data as images,text, stacks what ever you want really.

Comment: Here is an example of a list of phones images and details from a database displayed by a renderer.

http://coenraets.org/blog/2010/02/more-flex-4-spark-itemrenderer-samples/

Comment: So for as many ITEMS as are in the List you can draw as many of these little custom item display objects as you want (itemRenderers)